# Display message to use when app fails to get current position after X seconds

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I'm working on an ionic3 with angular 4 project which sometimes requires you get user current location. At times the internet could be slow making it difficult to get user's current position. 
What i want to achieve is after 30 seconds if the app fails to get the current position, an alert should be popped to the user telling him/her to try again.

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content : 'Checking Position...'
    })
    loader.present().then(()=>{
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        enableHighAccuracy:true,
        timeout: 3000
        }).then((resp) => {
          this.userlng = resp.coords.longitude;
          this.userlat = resp.coords.latitude;
          console.log('latitude '+this.userlat+ ' longitude '+this.userlng);

        })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the timeout and catchError functions from Angular's rxjs library. This basically sets a timeout of 30 seconds and throws a timeout error if location isn't fetched.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content : 'Checking Position...'
    })
    loader.present().then(()=>{
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        enableHighAccuracy:true,
        timeout: 3000
        }).then((resp) => {
          this.userlng = resp.coords.longitude;
          this.userlat = resp.coords.latitude;
          console.log('latitude '+this.userlat+ ' longitude '+this.userlng);

        }).pipe(timeout(30000),
            catchError(err => {
                alert(" " + err);
                throw("Error: "+ err);
    }))
    })
  }
```

Import catchError and timeout from rxjs.